# Percona Node fails to join: Operation not permitted

Tags: mysql, replication, percona, xtradb-cluster

Joining a new Percona node fails with:

```
130521  7:15:44 [Warning] WSREP: Failed to prepare for incremental state transfer: Local state UUID (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) does not match group state UUID (7ff38373-c1d1-11e2-0800-d595d1800e6a): 1 (Operation not permitted)
     at galera/src/replicator_str.cpp:prepare_for_IST():436. IST will be unavailable.
130521  7:15:44 [Note] WSREP: Node 0 (db-02.arqwifi) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 1 (db-01.arqwifi)(SYNCED) as donor.
130521  7:15:44 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 7101)
130521  7:15:44 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 1
```

Full error log:

- Host `/var/log/mysqld.log`, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1128435a85351a75574e
- Host `/var/lib/mysql/innobackup.backup.log`, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/218f9ff1882bb0f7848a
- Joiner `/var/log/mysqld.log`, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/92b5d29129b6ae72b3cd

Just in case, output of

```
ls -la /var/mysql/
ls -la /var/log/mysql/
ls -la /var/lib/mysql/
ls -la /var/run/mysqld/
ls -la /etc/my.cnf
```

- Host, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6bb685ce492a02ead7d4
- Joiner, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2dbf0a13121fd601940c

`SELINUX=disabled` is on both servers.

**Host**

```
[root@db-01 gajus]# xtrabackup --print-defaults
xtrabackup would have been started with the following arguments:
--character_set_server=utf8 --collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci --skip-name-resolve --innodb_file_per_table --log_slave_updates --server_id=155150 --wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/libgalera_smm.so --wsrep_node_address=10.128.155.150 --wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm:// --wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup --wsrep_cluster_name=live_cluster --wsrep_sst_auth=percona:[removed] --wsrep_slave_threads=1 --log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log --binlog_format=ROW --default_storage_engine=InnoDB --innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1 --innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2 --innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G --innodb_log_file_size=1G --query_cache_type=0 --query_cache_size=0 --join_buffer_size=4M --max_connections=1000 --table_cache=2000 --table_definition_cache=2000 --key_buffer_size=50M --sort_buffer_size=10M --read_rnd_buffer_size=1M --read_buffer_size=4M --tmp_table_size=500M --max_heap_table_size=1G --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --symbolic_links=0 --default_time_zone=+00:00 --max_allowed_packet=128MB
```

**Joiner**

```
[root@db-02 gajus]# xtrabackup --print-defaults
xtrabackup would have been started with the following arguments:
--character_set_server=utf8 --collation_server=utf8_unicode_ci --skip-name-resolve --innodb_file_per_table --log_slave_updates --server_id=155151 --wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/libgalera_smm.so --wsrep_node_address=10.128.155.151 --wsrep_cluster_address=gcomm://10.128.155.150 --wsrep_sst_method=xtrabackup --wsrep_cluster_name=live_cluster --wsrep_sst_auth=percona:[removed] --wsrep_slave_threads=1 --log_bin=/var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log --binlog_format=ROW --default_storage_engine=InnoDB --innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1 --innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2 --innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G --innodb_log_file_size=1G --query_cache_type=0 --query_cache_size=0 --join_buffer_size=4M --max_connections=1000 --table_cache=2000 --table_definition_cache=2000 --key_buffer_size=50M --sort_buffer_size=10M --read_rnd_buffer_size=1M --read_buffer_size=4M --tmp_table_size=500M --max_heap_table_size=1G --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --symbolic_links=0 --default_time_zone=+00:00 --max_allowed_packet=128MB
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in `percona-xtrabackup-2.1.2-611.rhel6.x86_64`. Downgrading to `percona-xtrabackup-2.0.7-552.rhel6.x86_64` solved the issue.